# Login not redirecting to next page

Tags: php, html

My login page is refusing to redirect to the home page but when the session verification code is taken off from the home page, it works. 
I am trying to ensure no user can access the home page without logging 
Please help me out . Thanks

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html><?php session_start();?>

<html>
<head>
 <title>User Login</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="login.php" method="post">
 <table width="500" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
 <tr align="center">
 <td colspan="3"><h2>User Login</h2></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td align="right"><b>Email</b></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>
 <td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required"></td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="3">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></body></html>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
 $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pass']);
 $sel_user = "select * from users where user_email='$email' AND    user_pass='$pass'";
 $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
 if (mysqli_num_rows($run_user)>0)
  {
 $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
  header('Location: home.php');
  }
 else {
 echo "<script>alert(' Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";

 }

 }

?>
```

Home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['nID']))
header("Location: index.php");
?>
<html>

welcome
</html>
```

session.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tech_dept");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$user_check=$_SESSION['leaders_username'];
$sel_user = "Select leaders_username from login where  leaders_username='$user_check'";
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['leaders_username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($con); 
header('Location: index.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: use `session_start();` in login.php file also

Comment: start session_start(); in login.php and you haven' t set value for $_SESSION['nID'] in login.php

Comment: For what purpose you are using Session.php.

Answer (score 0):

Remove login.php from your action

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Because of this action it will redirect to again login.php page

Comment: This won't do any good. How do you plan on getting the data from `Index.php` to `Login.php` if you remove the action?

Comment: Yes you are right. I think you want to use session_start(); in login.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start session in login.php file. Otherwise your session variable will not be set.

Comment: I have added session_start() in login.php and also set  $_SESSION['nID'] which now works but I can now access home.php without login. How can I fix this? I shouldn't be able to access home.php without login

Comment: I think that u have active session and home.php passing ur  check.. try to open ur page in "incognito window" and see

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. I had an active session but now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `session_start()` needs to be called on *all* pages that are going to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal in any way. It's a good idea to place it on every page though, as your session can in worst case expire without your intent.

In particular, your Login.php doesn't call `session_start()`. And most likely, [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would've told you about this (a PHP Notice: "*Undefined variable: _SESSION in ...*").

I also noticed that your Login.php doesn't set `$_SESSION['nID']`, but instead you set `$_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;`. You need to be consistent with your naming of variables. You can have more than one session, but from the looks of it, your code only sets `$_SESSION['user_email']`, while you use another session entirely. And then in sessions.php you use `$_SESSION['leaders_username']`. (What do you even use session.php for?

---

A note on security: You really, really, really should use prepared statements with bound variables to avoid SQL-injection. You're using an API that allows for this, so you should take advantage of it. You should read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: I have added session_start() in login.php and also set  $_SESSION['nID'] which now works but I can now access home.php without login. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think that u have active session and it just passing ur check.

Comment: @user2998991 Check that you have no kind of output prior to `header("Location: ...");` in your `home.php`. Also enable error-reporting [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)